# What to do with the questions having solutions in comments but unanswered?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, post-ban, unanswered-questions

I have got the problem solved here [Developer License for windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248443/developer-license-for-windows-8-1) by discussion in comments but the question remains unanswered.

1. Will it be treated as question with no proper response? Questions with no good response previously lead me to `post-ban` i.e. banned from asking questions.
2. Should I ask or wait for someone to answer?  or Should I write the answer myself and accept it?
3. Is it necessary for all the questions to get answered and accepted for it to be treated as a 'question with proper response'?

Comment: I realise the duplicate doesn't answer all three of your questions, but then again, you shouldn't be asking three different questions in a single post.